# Selecting certain segments when creating training set for classification in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, image-segmentation, image-classification, arcgis-10.7

I am trying to classify an RGB image in ArcGIS 10.7.

When I try to use the 'select segment' option to create a training set I am allowed to pick only certain segments to add to my training set. For example, if there are 3 segments next to each other that belong to 1 class I am sometimes only able to select 2 out of the 3 segments. I don't get an error message but I'm simply not allowed to add the 3rd segment to the class I want, for some reason. In the corner of the ArcGIS window I get the message 'Oversimplified training sample selected'.

I have been able to successfully classify the image before, so I dont think there's a problem with the image itself.

What could I be doing wrong that is preventing me from using certain segments (that really do belong to the class I'm trying to ID)?

[image: Image: Segment chosen is being pointed at and message is circled]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please provide a screenshot highlighting the issue? Are you certain the segment is actually a polygon and not a hole or area of no data?

Comment: Image is included! And yes, I'm certain that I'm choosing an actual segment and not a hole/nodata area.